# Can fresh citrus juice be reduced to concentrate flavor?

Tags: baking, fruit, citrus

Does reducing fresh citrus juice increase its flavor and will the flavor be damaged if it is reduced too far?

Comment: I have lemon & lime trees; want to make variations of a Key Lime pie, or just a citrusy pie. Fresh citrus has lots of water- feel like I should reduce- but, will it turn bitter?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. I am trying to figure out what your problem might be. As far as I can see, no other question has been asked from your account. I also don't see other questions matching your description having been posted in the last 3 months from other accounts. Are you sure you posted your earlier question? Maybe you typed it and then left the browser tab without posting?

Comment: Heating citrus does not increase flavor, it changes it, quite significantly. Cooked/heated citrus tastes much different than freshly squeezed.  What is it that you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Hi @FoodE. I took the liberty of rewording your question to hopefully make it clearer. My apologies if I have misunderstood your original question or otherwise messed it up.

Answer (score 5):

Heating citrus changes its flavor quite dramatically.  When and how much to heat and reduce citrus depends on the outcome you are looking to achieve.  If you want to preserve the fresh squeezed flavor, heating is not advisable.  If you are looking for a more reduced, cooked down flavor, heating can be good. Certainly, the flavor will be concentrated, but it will be different from the fresh juice. Ultimately, it is the application that matters.

Comment: Wow, all good perspectives; making me think more on what my ultimate goal really is; with that said, and based on this feed back.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to make here?

If you want something super intense, you can try adding a natural citrus oil (i.e lemon oil to lemon juice) for a more intense fragrance. If you're hoping to up the acidity you can add powdered citric acid.

Heating the juice will change the flavour quite dramatically. But you can also try dehydrating the liquid on a low temperature, or a freeze reduction.

Comment: I'd add zest rather than citrus oil, since if you have fresh citrus juice you've got the peel right there waiting to be zested anyway.

Comment: true! But if you want something totally homogeneous...another workaround I can think of is making olio saccharum.

Comment: Thank you-great site-truly pro's hanging out giving solid advise: I am going to make an olio saccharum, >because it's sticking with the citrus from my property< and sounds like I will get some citrus punch out of it. But, also, I am not a baker at heart, and the citric acid approach sounds as though it will get me that snappy-citrus I want, and neutralize the sweetness....I do"not want a sweet, sweet, pie"! Also, will definitely add the zest as well - it's so pure, right from the fruit tree. Note: I grow many herbs, fruits, vegetables; we call it  "Walk the menu". The Pie is important. Thk you